# Objective C - Matrix Multiplication Slow Performance

Tags: objective-c, matrix, nsmutablearray, multiplication, matrix-multiplication

I have 2 2-D NSMutableArrays and I am trying to do some basic matrix multiplication.  I have my generic formula code below, but its performance is exceptionally slow (as expected).  I have done lots of googling and have not found any easy nor easy to understand formulas to change up the code for performance enhancement.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of a straightforward formula/tutorial/example of how to get better performance than 0(n^3) with matrix multiplication in Objective C.

```
+ (NSMutableArray*)multiply:(NSMutableArray*)a1 withArray:(NSMutableArray*)a2
{
    if([[a1 objectAtIndex: 0] count] != [a2 count])
    {
        NSLog(@"Multiplicaton error!");
        return NULL;
    }

    int a1_rowNum = [a1 count];
    int a2_rowNum = [a2 count];
    int a2_colNum = [[a2 objectAtIndex:0] count];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:a1_rowNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < a1_rowNum; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *tempRow = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:a2_colNum];
        for (int j = 0; j < a2_colNum; j++) {
            double tempTotal = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < a2_rowNum; k++) {
                double temp1 = [[[a1 objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:k] doubleValue];
                double temp2 = [[[a2 objectAtIndex:k] objectAtIndex:j] doubleValue];
                tempTotal += temp1 * temp2;
            }
             //Stored as a string because I upload it to an online database for storage.
            [tempRow addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",tempTotal]];
        }
        [result addObject:tempRow];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested whether a C version will work better? And how big (dimension) are the 2 matrices?

Comment: The arrays are around 50-200 by 50-200.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will be much faster if you **Write it in C**.

---

`double[]` will be ridiculously fast compared to an `NSArray` of `NSNumber`s for this task. you'll have good cache coherency, minimal instructions, no need to go through the runtime or allocate in order to write or read an element. no need to perform reference count cycling on each element…

Comment: Is there an easy way to write this in C?  My issue is I only know Java aside from just taking up objective C, and I could not find a way to pass double[][] as a parameter to a "message" to the method.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma In that case, you might consider creating an objc class to hold your multidimensional arrays. Of course, you would want to avoid objc messaging for any/every read/write to that array. as well, `double` is potentially more accuracy than you need -- consider `float`. You could also put it in a struct, if you do not need reference counting.

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C. To write C in Objective-C, you literally do just that.

Comment: @WilburVandrsmith: Objective C is C only , but the things is when we 
send objectAtIndex, addObject messages to the NSMutableArray object, we do additional computations at runtime.
Which includes a lookup at the isa pointer understanding the message selector and then going to the corresponding function.
and this happens every single time and if the array id say 100 x 100
Its gonna take a toll at processing.

Comment: Either writing it in C completely, Or using Objective C's Runtime methods to optimize this code would be another option.
There are runtime methods which give actual C function for class' selector which can avoid unnecessary lookup at runtime.
but again Why invent something on your own when you have a powerful optimized library by Apple itself.
Moreover once you learn how to use it, It will always be useful later on.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar the BLAS answer is good (+1). however, i'd avoid the `IMP`+objc runtime approach -- that's using a bulldozer to move a chair.

Comment: @Justin:I know :P thats why I advice against it when my comment ends :)
Actually when I first looked at IMP and runtime methods in my early days into Objective C [which dates back to 6 months ago :P]
the example I saw for ist use-case was to do do complex mathematical calculations like Mtarix multiplication which requires same message being passed in long for loop.
Since then I always wanted to use it! I thought this might be the perfect scenario.
But then I found out that we have a framework as well.

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar I pointed that out because `IMP` caching was *worded* as an alternative solution for the problem. in reality, it won't come close to a C implementation regarding performance, resource usage, or readability. i was just trying to emphasize that it's not worth consideration (in this case), and would result in a *comparably* low speed improvement. one could spend a lot of time optimizing the program in the OP, but it's best to just approach it using C (BLAS or no BLAS).

Answer (score 4):

You need have a look at **Apple's Accelerate frameWork** for **ios4.0 onwards**.
You can do a lot of complex math and matrix manipulation with it and this framework is **optimized to run on any iOS hardware.**

Checkout:

https://developer.apple.com/performance/accelerateframework.html

Comment: Particularly, the `cblas_dgemm` function looks to be what you're looking for. Or `cblas_sgemm` if you just need single precision.